# Discord repeating bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making my first Discord bot and the idea is that when a user sends a message to a channel, the bot simply repeats it. I have this set up, but the problem is that it goes into a loop and just keeps repeating. How can I break that so he repeats only once?

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new Commando.Client();
bot.on('message', (message) => {
     if (message.content){ 
        message.channel.sendMessage(message.content);
    }

})
```

`

Comment: Most likely once your bot sees a message it repeats, so it is repeating itself.

Comment: I know it does, my question is how to break it so it repeats it only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `id` of the user that sent the message to make sure you're not repeating yourself. Assuming Commando has similar syntax to vanilla discord.js (it looks like it does), you can do this:

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new Commando.Client();
bot.on('message', (message) => {
     if (message.author.id !== bot.user.id && message.content){ 
        message.channel.sendMessage(message.content);
    }

})
```